# How to create a UITextField on SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

I want to implement a Textfield to input your name on my SpriteKit Game, so I have something like this:

```
SKLabelNode* gameTitle = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
gameTitle.text = @"Game Title";
gameTitle.name = @"gametitle";
gameTitle.fontSize = 44.0;
gameTitle.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
gameTitle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2 + 150);
[self addChild:gameTitle];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
textField.placeholder = @"Enter your name here";
textField.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.delegate = self.delegate;

[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

so, the problem is that it's not showed on my scene, maybe the problem is when adding it into the scene, I use addSubview.

Is that wrong?

Comment: try using a UITextView

Comment: @LearnCocos2D still the same, it doesn't appear :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add objects that inherits UIView's inside the `didMoveToView:(SKView *)view` function

Just add that function to your `SKScene` and move your `UITextField` inside:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
    textField.center = self.view.center;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter your name here";
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.delegate = self.delegate;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

Comment: Great and more effective solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I change to another Scene the the TextField stays in the view. Do I have to remove it manually?

Comment: unfortunately you will, @palme

Comment: Thanks! But how to remove it??

Comment: [textField removeFromSuperView]; @Frade

Answer (score 1):

to remove it use the

```
[myTextField removeFromSuperView];
```

if you don't want to use the method didMoveToView that insert the textField at the scene presentation, you can use this method:

```
-(void)insertUI{

ttaAppDelegate *myDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *vc = myDel.window.rootViewController;
self.textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2+20, 200, 40)];
self.textField.center = self.view.center;
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
self.textField.placeholder = @"Enter your name here";
self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
self.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self.textField.delegate = self;
self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(saveScore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.button setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[vc.view addSubview:self.textField];
[vc.view addSubview:self.button];
vc.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
[vc requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
}
```