# Is there a way to use UITextField in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have some strings in array. And I need them to be displayed in SpriteKit game. They could be pretty long so SKLabelNode is a bad choice for it. I want to use something that will automatically fill the field with text from array. How can one do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658072/how-to-create-a-uitextfield-on-spritekit/19661737#19661737

Comment: @iPrabu I would not say that. At first, my question is about swift. And second, I'm asking for any way to fill text field from array. Not specifically UITextField, that's just the only one I know. Also in that question nobody explained how to "connect" text field with an array.

Comment: Could you not use a multi line `SKLabelNode`? http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.co.za/2014/12/multiline-sklabelnode-hell-yes-please-xd.html

Comment: @sbarow I've tried their swift code and it's not working. Specifically on "sharedInstance" and "countElements" part. How can I try it's Obj-C code in swift file?

Comment: @Burundanga what code are you using? Their project or one of the links they posted to on Github? FYI using Obj-C file with swift https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps

Comment: Swift code from the top comment from your link.